# Ext.MessageBox overflow problem

Tags: extjs, overflow, messagebox

```
Ext.MessageBox.show({
       title: '',
       msg: '',
       height:300,
       width:500,
       maxWidth:1000,
       maxHeight:1000,
       minWidth:500,
       buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OKCANCEL,
       multiline: true,
       fn: showResultText,
       value: something
   });

function showResultText(btn, text){
    if(btn=='ok'){
            $.post(url, {clientcomment:text, orderid:orderid}, function(data){
                    $('div#something').html(data);


                    });
    }
};
```

Now say if someone were to enter a very long string with no returns, what returns is a very long string horizontally, it will not stay in the div I put it :( I dont really know how to fix, I dont want an overflow bar horizontally I would like it to move down a line when it reaches the end of the div.

Comment: I've merged your unregistered account into your registered account. Thanks for registering :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How is you div styled? If it has a specified width and `white-space: normal`, the text should wrap.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer jd, i retested it today and I think my problem is that I was testing it ... as if people were too dumb, IE not adding any whitespaces and your comment made me think of that. So What I was putting in for test was "fkjdahsjkghaljhgj" x 10 but testing again with "5u84195 insert whitespace here " x 10 and now it works. and thanks for the whitespace! I never even knew about that one :)